# Can I use 是 with adjective (color)?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

In my work book I saw the sentence: 现在这个咖啡的颜色好一点，不是很黑

My question is: if 黑 (in 不是很黑) is an adjective, why it is used with 是? should it be 不太黑？

Comment: Why do you think 是 cannot be used with adjectives?

Comment: Because you use it to connect 2 nouns:  Noun 1 + 是 + Noun 2.  Is there a rule that states that you can use 是 with adjective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 不是很黑， 是 is used as a linking verb. In a negative sentence, when we have 很 modify an adjective, 是 should be used. E.g. 他不是很好，她不是很漂亮. Well, 他不很好 and 她不很漂亮 aren't natural.

However, without 很, we don't use 是 in such sentences. E.g. 她不漂亮, not 她不是漂亮. There's also an emphasis 是 and the position of 是 is moved to "before 是", like 是不 instead of 不是. E.g. 她是不漂亮. 他是不好. etc.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation!!!

Answer (score 1):

是 has many different meanings/usages, one of them is semi-equivalent to "be" in English. Just like "be" can be used with adjectives, it's perfectly fine to use 是 with adjectives, e.g., 咖啡是黑色的。

It is true that, especially in the presence of adverbs like 很/有点, 是 is often omitted, E.g., 咖啡很苦。However, even then you can still use 是 for emphasis or concession in an affirmation: 咖啡是很苦。In a negation, using 不是很黑vs不很黑 doesn't have any discernible difference in most contexts.

Answer (score -1):

"很" is an adverb that means "very or too". Here it modifies the adjective "黑" (dark). You can think of this sentence as saying "现在这个咖啡的颜色好一点了，不是很黑 - "Now the color of the coffee looks a little better, (it) **isn't(不是)** very dark", **or** "Now the color of the coffee looks a little better, **not(不)** very dark".

"不是(isn't/not)很黑(very dark)" = "不(not)很黑(ver dark)". Similarly, 不是太黑 = 不太黑. Here, "是" can be treated as an auxiliary word that has no specific meaning/function, and can be eliminated without changing the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: So what is the purpose of 是 in this case?

Comment: Please see the revision above.